# filtrar tabela asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Preciso filtrar uma tabela, que esta em uma partial view, dependendo do parametro digitado em um campo, que é passado para o controller via ajax. Como recarrego a tabela com o filtro aplicado?

Parte da index onde esta minha partial

```
<div class="row" id="partial">
   @{Html.RenderPartial("Partial_table", Model);}
</div>
```

Partial view, onde é carregado a tabela

```
@model IEnumerable<OAP.Web.MVC.Corp.Models.CorpCRM>


<div style="overflow: auto; height: 700px">
<table id="tbEstatica" class="myTable">

    <tr class="myTable">
        <th class="myTable">Data</th>
        <th class="myTable">Matricula</th>
        <th class="myTable">Produto</th>
        <th class="myTable">Contrato</th>
        <th class="myTable">Penumber</th>
        <th class="myTable">Nome Cliente</th>
        <th class="myTable">Valor</th>
        <th class="myTable">Agencia / Conta</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        @{

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <tr style="height: 50px" class="myTable">
                    <td class="myTable">@item.Dt_Contab</td>
                    <td class="myTable">@item.Matricula</td>
                    <td class="myTable">@item.Produto</td>
                    <td class="myTable">@item.Contrato</td>
                    <td class="myTable">@item.Penumber</td>
                    <td class="myTable">@item.Nome_Cliente</td>
                    <td class="myTable">@item.Valor</td>
                    <td class="myTable">@item.Agencia_Conta</td>
                </tr>
            }

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ajax que passa o parametro do campo;

```
<script>
function Buscar() {


     $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/RetornaCorp")',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                produto: $("#Produto").val()

            },
            succes: function (data) {
                $("#partial").html(data);
            }
     });



}
```

Controller que recebe o parametro do Ajax

```
 public ActionResult RetornaCorp(int Produto)
    {
        CorpDAO dao = new CorpDAO();
        listaCRM = dao.ListarCorp(Produto);

        return PartialView("Partial_table", listaCRM);
    }
```

Comment: Acho que não entendi. Você já está filtrando os dados, não?

Comment: quando eu clico no botão para fazer este fluxo, o parâmetro chega no controller mas não filtra a tabela. Não sei se estou fazendo algo errado, na hora de passar isso para a tela

Comment: Poste o seu método `ListarCorp(produto)`. Você sabe [debugar o seu código](http://codingcraft.com.br/2016/06/20/video-depurando-ou-depurando-seu-sistema-no-visual-studio/) para ver se está passando os valores corretos? Dá algum erro no console (F12) ao clicar no botão?

Comment: Então, ele devolve a lista certinho, filtrada. Só não esta mostrando na tela o resultado do filtro

Comment: No console do browser (F12) aparece algum erro?

Comment: no ajax tá faltando um "s" no `succes`. tem que ser `success`

Comment: Não acredito que era um "s", obrigado pessoal. Já estava depressivo, por não conseguir fazer isso. hahahaha

Answer (score 3):

Colocando como resposta para ajudar a quem tiver o mesmo problema. <strike>(ou quem tem preguiça de ler comentarios)</strike>

O erro acontece devido à um erro de digitação na função `success` do `$.ajax`:

```
function Buscar() {
     $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/RetornaCorp")',
            type: 'POST',
            data:
            {
                produto: $("#Produto").val()
            },
            success: function (data) { //Coreção aqui, adicionando um "S"
                $("#partial").html(data);
            }
     });
}
```